# Python Selenium differentiate two icon with same name to press one

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying Selenium press Los Angeles word but on the No-professional part.For that I need to press Skate first but in the No-professional part and after press Los Angeles.

To chose between Professional and No-professional I tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//class[contains(., 'Skate:')][1]").click()` (where [1] should set the no profesional part) but is not working.

Second I tried with the completely xpath `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='sidebar']/div/ul/li[2]/ul/li[12]/ul/li[4]/span").click()`, the problem is the xpath changes everyday so I cannot use it. Here is the HTML Code.

```
 <li class="level-1 profesional ">
                  <span class="text"><span class="trigger" title="Professional"></span>Professional</span>

                        <ul style="">


           <li class="level-2 collapse">
                                  <span class="text"><span class="sport-icon skate" title="Skate"></span>Skate</span>
        <ul style="display:none">
                <li class="collapse">
      <span class="text"><span class="trigger" title="Los Angeles"></span>Los Angeles</span>
            <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="">
        <a class="text " href="/es/professional/skate/los-angeles/los-angeles--challenge">
            Los Angeles - Challenge
            <div class="marker"></div>
        </a>
    </li>
            </ul>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
   <li class="level-1 no-professional ">
           <span class="text"><span title="No professional" class="trigger"></span>No professional</span>

                               </li>
                                <li class="level-2 collapse">
                                  <span class="text"><span title="Skate" class="sport-icon skate"></span>Skate</span>
        <ul style="display:none">

    <li class="collapse">
      <span class="text"><span title="Los Angeles" class="trigger"></span>Los Angeles</span>
            <ul style="display: none;">
    <li class="">
        <a href="/es/no-professional/skate/los-angeles/los-angeles--challenge"" class="text ">
            Los Angeles - Challenge
            <div class="marker"></div>
        </a
    </li>
```

Please could you help me.

Comment: can you able to provide the URL on which you are testing @Johnny007

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!The website doesn't have link for the moment 'cos is being developing by my colleague, is not online yet. On the one hand I'm developing  the scraper program and on the other hand he is developing the website which by it will read the data. If it can be more helpful I can post all the code page. I'm sorry to don't be able to provide more data.